# C Socket API Call with Swift

Tags: networking, swift, socket

I have a small function in Objective-C which uses the C Socket API to check if the device has an active internet connection:

> ```
> #include <netdb.h>
>
> - (BOOL)isNetworkAvailable {
>     char *hostname;
>     struct hostent *hostinfo;
>     hostname = "youtube.com";
>     hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname);
>     if (hostinfo == NULL) {
>         return NO;
>     } else {
>         return YES;
>     }
> }
> ```

I have rewritten this function in Swift, using an `UnsafeMutablePointer` type for the `hostent` struct:

```
func isNetworkAvailable() -> Bool {
    var hostinfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<hostent>
    let hostString: String = "youtube.com"
    var hostname = (hostString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
    hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname)
    if (hostinfo == nil) {
        hostinfo.destroy()
        return false
    } else {
        hostinfo.destroy()
        return true
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to check for network connectivity in Swift without using the C API?  How can I improve this function, possibly removing the need to manually retain and release an `UnsafeMutablePointer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Wrong memory management

`gethostbyname()` returns a pointer to an internal structure. You don't
have initialized that memory and don't own it, therefore you must not
call `destroy()`.

#### Things that can be improved

```
var hostinfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<hostent>
// ...
hostinfo = gethostbyname(...)
```

can be combined to

```
let hostinfo = gethostbyname(...)
```

There is no need to declare the variable in advance, and the type
can be inferred automatically. Also you can define it as a constant
with `let` because it is not modified subsequently.

```
let hostString: String = "youtube.com"
var hostname = (hostString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
let hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname)
```

can be simplified to

```
let hostname = "youtube.com"
let hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname)
```

because a Swift string is automatically converted to a C string when
passed to a C API taking a `const char *` parameter.

Finally, since the `destroy()` has been removed,

```
if (hostinfo == nil) {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

can be simplified to

```
return hostinfo != nil
```

So your function is now

```
func isNetworkAvailable() -> Bool {
    let hostname = "youtube.com"
    let hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname)
    return hostinfo != nil
}
```

#### BUT: This does not what you expect it to do!

`gethostbyname()` "only" resolves a host name to an IP address.
That does not necessarily involve any network communication, as
the local DNS resolver might have cached the information.

#### Better: Use the SCNetworkReachability framework.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html):

> The SCNetworkReachability programming interface allows an application
>   to determine the status of a system's current network configuration
>   and the reachability of a target host. A remote host is considered
>   reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network
>   stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee
>   that the data packet will actually be received by the host.

Other Resources:

- Apple provides Objective-C sample code at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html
- A Swift wrapper can be found here: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift
- And perhaps you can use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/working-with-c-structs-in-swift.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  Ideally, I wrote this script so I wouldn't have to include the Reachability dependency in my project.  Is there a way to expand on the current implementation to do a basic network check without a third-party dependency?

Comment: @JAL: The SO thread that I linked to does not use any 3rd party dependency. `import SystemConfiguration` is sufficient.